# How can you easily store a string using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

Right now, my program has a tweeting system. I want to be able to save the current tweet whenever there's an update, and save the last tweeted thing. Then, every 10 minutes, a rake script runs and the tweet gets sent out. This is to prevent multiple tweets. The problem is that I have no way of saving the last tweeted phrase. I've tried using something like:

```
MY_VARS = {}
```

in application.rb, and then using `MY_VARS[:old] = MY_VARS[:current]`, but that keeps being overridden. I also tried using the caching in rails, specifically:

```
Rails.cache.write("current", myTweet)
```

But that gets overridden to nil everytime the script runs. Does anyone know how I should be doing this?

Comment: Why can't you store it in your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place is to store it at some file, since it's a worker script it's not that important to be fast, in your case

Comment: Huh? Not sure what you are saying.

Comment: Ok, i just read that there is no problem on changing the object that a constant refers to. I just started learning Ruby last week so... yeah. I edited my answer